# NextJS Rewrites keeps on refreshing

Tags: javascript, next.js, url-rewriting, url-routing

I've two projects,

- **Project 1** - React + Electrode - *[www.example.com/au](http://www.example.com/au)*
- **Project 2** - Next Js - *[www.example.com/au/sell-your-car](http://www.example.com/au/sell-your-car)*

**Project 2** has a middleware to detect whether the **request** is coming from **desktop/mobile**.

The **Project 2** page folder looks like the following:

- pages

  - _viewport

    - desktop

      - au

        - sell-your-car
    - mobile

      - au

        - sell-your-car

> _middleware.tsx

```
function getViewport(userAgent: UserAgent | null | undefined) {
  if (!userAgent?.ua) return;
  const isMobile = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(userAgent.ua);
  return isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop";
}

/** @type {import("next/server").NextMiddleware} */

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();

  // Prevent internals from being accessed canonically
  // (i.e. if you try to go to example.com/_viewport it should give a 404)
  if (url.pathname.startsWith(`/_viewport`)) {
    return new Response(null, { status: 404 });
  }

  const viewport = getViewport(req.ua);

  url.pathname = `_viewport/${viewport}${url.pathname}`;

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url);
}
```

I want to set up rewrites in such a way that they should support all the routes after the **/sell-your-car** route.

e.g.

- *[www.example.com/au/sell-your-car](http://www.example.com/au/sell-your-car)*
- *[www.example.com/au/sell-your-car/1](http://www.example.com/au/sell-your-car/1)*
- *[www.example.com/au/sell-your-car/1/2](http://www.example.com/au/sell-your-car/1/2)* (and so on)

Other than that all the routes should redirect to the Project 1 (React)

> next.config.js

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "/:path*"
      },
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "http://localhost:3001/:path*" // Rewrite non-migrated routes to Create React App
      }
    ];
  }
```

With the current config, the **/sell-your-car** page is getting refreshed continuously.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also tackled this issues on this thread:
[Next.JS 13 using appdir -> Page keeps refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883914/next-js-13-using-appdir-page-keeps-refreshing/77893260#77893260)

In short you have to make some updates, just run in your root folder:
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest~

- All the best!