# Next.JS 13 using appdir -> Page keeps refreshing

Tags: reactjs, next.js, refresh

My Next.JS 13 app which uses appDir feature, keeps on refreshing for no obvious reason.
That documentation does not help me. This is what my output tells me to do:

```
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
```

Comment: can you show us your code from the component that's giving this error ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no information about which component causes this error.

Comment: if that's the case, you have to make sure that all of your component name is in ```PascalCase``` not ```CamelCase```. And make sure too that you only have one component export each file

Answer (score 2):

What you did is valid, but doesn't solve the issue, you just stalled a bit..
I took time to go a bit deeper, so here's the deal .. there is some kind of bug in fast-reload which appear in older versions.. then there was a proposal to vercel to make a config were you can disabled fast-reload and.. they refused motivating that the fast-reload is an essential feature for nextjs and they managed to solved it, so what you have to do is to run:

npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest

as of the latest versions the issue is solved.

- All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by re-installing node_modules. Not sure what was the problem. I also removed .nextjs folder.